# Unity Web Request: Please enable JavaScript to access the website

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, http-post

So I'm trying to access the info of a website that requires JavaScript to see the actual body. Is there a way to bypass this or maybe a way to enable JavaScript for UWR?

Comment: Even though the website uses JavaScript, I'm assuming you're trying to use GET and POST requests? The forms are still there, did you try to use them?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is executed by the client - *web browser*, for example. UnityWebRequest can't do that.

You can try:

1. **Try reading page's JavaScript by yourself**: you can open a page in your browser, and read what JavaScript actually doing to get data which you want. 
   In Chrome you can use dev tools. You are most interested in [Network](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) tab and [Sources](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript). After that, you can recreate web requests in Unity, and get data.
2. **Use the real browser inside your project**: like [this one](https://bitbucket.org/vitaly_chashin/simpleunitybrowser/src/default/), import it, then load page, and then get HTML page text from the API of this browser. **But this is the bad case**, because you will integrate the whole web browser inside a game engine. Plus it's not cross-platform friendly.
3. **Use website's API**: this is the best case, but the website may not have public API at all. You should investigate.
4. **Write your own parser**: this is a compromise, but requires time and skill to accomplish. You can use any language to scrape website (i mean, don't use game engine for that), such as C# ([tutorial on that, but it's in russian](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZm3dNVfO8E)), or [Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcnomT0CP0Y), and then create a server with your own API from your parser, or communicate your project and parser in any way you like.